# Ending a while loop with a predetermined input in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, loops

I'm writing a small script that will take miles input by user and gallons input and show the number of trips and the miles per gallon of the total trips taken. Here's what I have.

```
public class FuelEfficiency 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double totalMiles = 0;
        double totalGallons = 0;
        int tripCounter = 0;

        while (tripCounter > -1)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter miles driven: "); //Want to say "Enter miles driven or 'q' to quit: "
            double milesDriven = input.nextDouble();
            totalMiles = totalMiles + milesDriven;

            System.out.print("Enter gallons of gas consumed: "); // Similar to the above.
            double gasConsumed = input.nextDouble();
            totalGallons = totalGallons + gasConsumed;

            tripCounter = tripCounter + 1;

            double milesPerGallon = totalMiles / totalGallons;

        System.out.printf("%nYour number of trips is: %s%n", tripCounter);
        System.out.printf("Your mileage per gallon of gas consumed is: %s%n%n", milesPerGallon);
        }


    }

}
```

As it is right now, the loop will continue indefinitely. What I want to do is be able to accept a predefined input (like 'quit' or 'q') to end the loop and report the previous trip and milePerGallon without making a new equation or adding another trip. (I have also thought of trying to continue the loop until a value of '0' is entered. I suspect I would be using milesDriven and gasConsumed to loop that way. But whenever I tried that it would still take those values into account when it runs the new milePerGallon.)

Any tips on what I should use to do this?

Comment: A quick look into the API of Scanner finds me `findInputInHorizon` which you could use to find `q`. I've never used it though.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it still counts the 0 in your code is because the calculations come after the input. To fix this you could change your code like this. So the if statement makes sure the value is above 0, before the calculations run.

```
    while (milesDriven>0)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter miles driven: "); //Want to say "Enter miles driven or 'q' to quit: "
                double milesDriven = input.nextDouble();
                if (milesDrive>0)
                {
                totalMiles = totalMiles + milesDriven;

                System.out.print("Enter gallons of gas consumed: "); // Similar to the above.
                double gasConsumed = input.nextDouble();
                totalGallons = totalGallons + gasConsumed;

                tripCounter = tripCounter + 1;

                double milesPerGallon = totalMiles / totalGallons;
                }
            System.out.printf("%nYour number of trips is: %s%n", tripCounter);
            System.out.printf("Your mileage per gallon of gas consumed is: %s%n%n", milesPerGallon);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is be able to accept a predefined input (like 'quit'
>   or 'q') to end the loop and report the previous trip and milePerGallon
>   without making a new equation or adding another trip.

Firstly, I wanted to state that even though I can understand why you've `tripCounter > -1` as your `while loop` conditions, it doesn't make much sense as you're always incrementing `tripCounter` hence the condition will never become `false`. With that in mind we can simplify it to `while(true)` then basically `break` whenever the user decides to quit.

**Solution:**

Considering what you've mentioned, we could use a `Stack` to store the records after each iteration and basically when a user decides to quit then we can simply `pop` the last record and display it.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

double totalMiles = 0;
double totalGallons = 0;
int tripCounter = 0;
Stack<String> trips = new Stack<>();

while (true){
     System.out.print("Enter miles driven: "); //Want to say "Enter miles driven or 'q' to quit: "
     String milesInput = input.next();
     if(milesInput.equalsIgnoreCase("q") || milesInput.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
          if(trips.empty()) {
              System.out.println("no data entered");
              break;
          }

          String[] previousRecord  = trips.pop().split(" ");
          System.out.printf("%nYour number of trips is: %s%n", previousRecord[0]);
          System.out.printf("Your mileage per gallon of gas consumed is: %s%n%n", previousRecord[1]);
          break;
     }
     double milesDriven = Double.parseDouble(milesInput); // consider adding extra checks before converting
     totalMiles = totalMiles + milesDriven;

     System.out.print("Enter gallons of gas consumed: "); // Similar to the above.
     String gallonsInput = input.next();
     if(gallonsInput.equalsIgnoreCase("q") || gallonsInput.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
         if(trips.empty()) {
             System.out.println("no data entered");
             break;
         }
         String[] previousRecord  = trips.pop().split(" ");
         System.out.printf("%nYour number of trips is: %s%n", previousRecord[0]);
         System.out.printf("Your mileage per gallon of gas consumed is: %s%n%n", previousRecord[1]);
         break;
     }
     double gasConsumed = Double.parseDouble(gallonsInput);
     totalGallons = totalGallons + gasConsumed;

     tripCounter = tripCounter + 1;

     double milesPerGallon = totalMiles / totalGallons;
     trips.push(tripCounter + " " + milesPerGallon);

     System.out.printf("%nYour number of trips is: %s%n", tripCounter);
     System.out.printf("Your mileage per gallon of gas consumed is: %s%n%n", milesPerGallon);
}
```

What I have added on top of your code:

- [**Stack data structure**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)
- [**split(String regex)**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))
- [**equalsIgnoreCase()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_equalsignorecase.htm)
- [**Double.parseDouble()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/double_parsedouble.htm)
- [**Break statement**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_break_statement.htm)